# Is my PSU fried?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, crash

My pc just shut off out of nowhere last night and won't turn back on. Today I have disconnected everything from it and only left the psu and mb connected, my (vanity lights?) And start button light all come on but when I press start it just doesn't boot up, no post, status codes, nothing. The first time I press start when power is applied the fans do the same thing jumping pin 4 & 5 do (see video) but after the first twitch of the fan nothing happens, and pressing start again does nothing.

I read up quite a bit and found people having similar issues, but no one ever said how it was resolved. I have attempted to flashback my bios but it is failing (blinks for 5 seconds then stays solid forever) I used a sandisk 16gb flash drive with my renamed cap file on the root of the drive formatted to FAT32 (just as the instructions say to) yet it will not update the bios. I also disconnected all power from the mb and jumped pin 4 and 5 to test the PSU the fan spins and shuts off repeatedly, and I do not know if that is normal behavior.

I have an Asus maximus vi hero MB and an EVGA nex750b PSU

When I apply power to the MB these are the lights that come on:
View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/siJiL.jpg

And this is a video of the PSU when I jump pin 4 & 5: View: https://youtu.be/5pV0P7wwg0I

Comment: Just to make sure it's not the MB playing hide and seek: remove the CMOS battery for a couple of seconds and put it back.  Retry power on.

Comment: I failed to mention (sorry) I have also tried resetting the CMOS by removing the battery, I left it out for probably a half hour (got sidetracked lol)

Comment: Focus, @GiЯ, focus!  Your MB may not want to boot without GPU or Memory.  Do you have a spare GPU you can try?  Every memory stick separately?  How long have you had this config?  Check for a short behind the MB.

Comment: I actually have 2 gpus in this build (2 RTX 2080's) i will try each one individually along with each ram sick individually and post back,  thank you for this suggestion.  I have had this configuration since I built it, I'm not sure exactly a time, but I want to say almost 2 1/2 years?  maybe more....

Comment: Which makes a short unlikely. Maybe your PSU had enough of the two RTX'en. Some overclocking perhaps?

Comment: I figure you would have tried this already if so, but just in case, do you have a known-good PSU you can test on that computer? Or a known-good computer you can test with that PSU?